# Issue using static framework crashlytics

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have a A.framework which i am using in my swift app Test.

A.framework has a podspec which has s.dependency = 'Crashlytics'

Now when i do pod install on swift app Test, in Test's podfile i have to write below since i am using static framework:

```
pre_install do |installer|
    # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
    def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
end
```

Now when i compile Test, it give me 'Crashlytics, file not found error'.
If i manually go to Test->Pods->A->Link binary with library->browse and add crashlytics.framework, error goes away.

How can i add a run script which will automate this manual step for me.

Thanks.